# Using Array.prototype.sort.call to sort a HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

```
var down=function(a,b){alert(a)}
Array.prototype.sort.call(table.tBodies[0].childNodes,down)
Array.prototype.sort.call([0,1,2,3],down)
```

Why do I not get alerts from the first sort call?

Comment: Maybe `childNodes` are empty?

Comment: nope sorry, plenty of childNodes available in tBodies[0]

Comment: test=table.tBodies[0].childNodes[2].childNodes[0].innerHTML

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Convert the `NodeList` to an array first:

```
var elements = [].slice.call(table.tBodies[0].childNodes);
```

and then call `sort` normally:

```
elements.sort(down);
```

It seems `sort` cannot handle *array-like* objects. This is probably because `NodeList` does not provide any methods to change the list, but `sort` sorts the array *in-place*.

**Update:** For more information, from the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.11):

> Perform an implementation-dependent sequence of calls to the [[Get]] , [[Put]], and [[Delete]] internal methods of *obj*.

I assume `NodeList`s don't have these internal methods. But this is really just an assumption. It could also be that this is implementation dependent.

I also suggest you use [`.children` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.children) instead of `.childNodes` to only get element nodes. **Update:** Or [`.rows`  *<sup>[DOM Spec]</sup>*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-52092650) as @patrick suggests.

Comment: Why would that help? ECMA-262 defines both `slice` _and_ `sort` to be generic functions that can be applied on anything that has appropriate attributes. It does warn that it may not work for host objects, but is there any particular reason why `slice` would work better on a DOM list than `sort`?

Comment: @Felix: Or maybe use `.rows` instead of `.children` for greater compatibility. I wonder what it is about `.sort()` that doesn't allow an Array-like object the way `.slice()` does. EDIT: Regarding your update, that makes sense. +1

Comment: @Henning: See my latest update. [The specification says](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.4.11): *"Perform an implementation-dependent sequence of calls to the [[Get]] , [[Put]], and [[Delete]] internal methods of `obj`"* I assume `NodeList`s don't have these internal methods... but I could be wrong. In any case, it definitly works this way.

Comment: @Felix: Hmm, you're right. Acoording to DOM Core, a `NodeList` is not necessarily mutable, so trying to sort it has no right to work.

Answer (score 8):

My proposal to sort an HTMLCollection is:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var parentNode = document.getElementById('test-list');
  var e = document.getElementById('test-list').children;
  [].slice.call(e).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent);
  }).forEach(function(val, index) {
    parentNode.appendChild(val);
  });
}
```

```html
<ol id="test-list">
    <li class="lang">Scheme</li>
    <li class="lang">JavaScript</li>
    <li class="lang">Python</li>
    <li class="lang">Ruby</li>
    <li class="lang">Haskell</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: In case someone like me wonders, there is no need to call `val.remove()`, because `appendChild()` does it automatically.

Comment: A one-line HTMLCollection sort, inspired by your answer: `[...document.getElementsByClassName("lang")].sort( (a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent) ).forEach( (val) => val.parentNode.appendChild(val) );`

Answer (score 1):

I correct the code of gaetanoM, this one works with IE :

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var parentNode = document.getElementById('test-list');
  var e = document.getElementById('test-list').children;
  [].slice.call(e).sort(function(a, b) {
   if (a.textContent > b.textContent) return 1;
  if (a.textContent < b.textContent) return -1;
  return 0;
   }).forEach(function(val) {
    parentNode.appendChild(val);
  });
}
```

```html
<ol id="test-list">
    <li class="lang">Scheme</li>
    <li class="lang">JavaScript</li>
    <li class="lang">Python</li>
    <li class="lang">Ruby</li>
    <li class="lang">Haskell</li>
    <li class="lang">Tata</li>
    <li class="lang">Aaaaa</li>
    <li class="lang">Drue</li>
</ol>
```