# JavaScript Array.prototype.sort() CAN NOT call on DOM.HTMLLIElements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, frontend, v8

I want to use `Array.prototype.sort()` to sort DOM.Element.

I try like this:

```js
    var e = document.getElementById('test-list').children;
    
    [].forEach.call(e,function(ee){
        console.log(ee);
    }); 
    // print each child in e
    
    [].sort.call([3,4,1],function(a,b){
        console.log(a+","+b);
    }); 
    // 3,4; 4,1; [3, 4, 1]; compares every two elements
    
    
    [].sort.call(e,function(a,b){
        console.log(a+","+b);
    }); 
    // CAN NOT work! don't print anything.
```

```html
    <ol id="test-list">
        <li class="lang">Scheme</li>
        <li class="lang">JavaScript</li>
        <li class="lang">Python</li>
        <li class="lang">Ruby</li>
        <li class="lang">Haskell</li>
    </ol>
```

Base on API of `Array.prototype.sort()` , `sort()` can be used on normal Objects more than basic type.

And I found

```
e[0].innerText = 232; // <li class="lang">232</li> ;works
e[0] = "123"; //<li class="lang">232</li> ;not work
```

So I assumed because of the fact that elements in Array of HTMLLIElements can not be changed directly, `sort()` somehow figured it out. So `sort()` just jump out and return.

Is that right? And what's the institution helps `sort()` decide whether deal with the Array?

Comment: Try converting to array like this `Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementById('test-list').children )`.

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call` equals `[].slice.call` from [Most efficient way to convert an HTMLCollection to an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array) . And it really worked the same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059090/array-prototype-sort-call

Comment: Do you just want to get a sorted array in JavasScript, or do you want to effectively rearrange the elements within the DOM?

Comment: Effectively rearrange the elements within the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! Unlike Chrome, which dies silently, the latest Firefox is more helpful:

> TypeError: HTMLCollection doesn't have an indexed property setter for '0'

which makes the problem clear: you cannot apply `sort` to an object that doesn't have numeric property setters (because `sort` attempts to sort in place and fails).

Comment: ...which means you have to convert it to an array first before you can sort it

Comment: Because I want to effectively rearrange the elements within the DOM. I just rewrite a new sort() which use `dom[i].innerText <--> dom[j].innerText;` to sort in place.