# Get info from a class and turn it to an array

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently building a sort system, and I want to sort these four elements, which all have the same class.

```js
      function sortByOrdnr() {

        var allaOrdnr = document.getElementsByClassName("ordernummer");

        var antal = allaOrdnr.length;

        var listWithAllaOrdnr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < antal; i++) {
          listWithAllaOrdnr.push(allaOrdnr[i]);
        }

        listWithAllaOrdnr.sort() // [A, B, C, E]

        console.log(listWithAllaOrdnr);
        for (var i = 0; i < antal; i++) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("ordernummer")[i] = listWithAllaOrdnr[i];

        }


      }
```

```html
<button onclick="sortByOrdnr()"> Button </button>

    <p class="ordernummer"> A </p>
    <p class="ordernummer"> E </p>
    <p class="ordernummer"> B </p>
    <p class="ordernummer"> C </p>
```

In the end, I want the classes to change position, so that the four elements are sorted when clicking on the button, like this:

```
<p class="ordernummer"> A </p>
<p class="ordernummer"> B </p>
<p class="ordernummer"> C </p>
<p class="ordernummer"> E </p>
```

I appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Array sorting doesn't work like that for HTML elements

Comment: What is the right method then?

Comment: You'll need to provide your own function to `sort` that uses the text inside the elements for comparison.

Comment: Check "innerHTML" or "innerText" to find value of your html elements. Then manually sort your array based on the value, then rewrite HTML in correct order with jquery

Comment: @LMinor I cant give you out the answer but just hints. and as I was typing this comment, Flo gave you the hints :)

Comment: instead of pushing the whole element into the array, push only the html element value, you should replace this line `listWithAllaOrdnr.push(allaOrdnr[i]);` to be like this `listWithAllaOrdnr.push(allaOrdnr[i].innerHTML);`

Comment: @Mohammad imo this is not bad idea to keep the whole elements in array, because it will be easier to rewrite HTML thanks to those full elements (after ordering) instead of retrieving them thanks to their value.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Of course I forgot the innerHTML.

Comment: @Flo In this context there is no requirement to hold  the entire element since all the elements are the same except for their `innerHTML`

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt only OP knows :) i thought it could be sample values and the "real" content could be much more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll provide another DOM version using plain ES6 JS which sorts HTMLElements in place based on their textContent. This is a helper function which I partly derived from [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36675806/5514077).

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.sort = function() {
  [...this]
    .sort( (a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent) )
    .forEach( (val) => val.parentNode.appendChild(val) );
}
```

After including this, you may use .sort() directly on the NodeList.

**Demo:**

```js
function sortByOrdnr() {
  var allaOrdnr = document.getElementsByClassName("ordernummer");
  allaOrdnr.sort();
}

HTMLCollection.prototype.sort = function() {
  [...this]
    .sort( (a, b) => a.textContent.localeCompare(b.textContent) )
    .forEach( (val) => val.parentNode.appendChild(val) );
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sortByOrdnr()"> Button </button>

<p class="ordernummer"> A </p>
<p class="ordernummer"> E </p>
<p class="ordernummer"> B </p>
<p class="ordernummer"> C </p>
```

Comment: Very elegant - this was what I was trying to achieve in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56078671/295783) - I would likely not use the reserved word `sort` but something like `sortByContent`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a DOM version

```js
function sortByOrdnr() {
  const oDiv = document.getElementById("container");
  const ps = oDiv.querySelectorAll("p");
  let vals = [];
  ps.forEach(p => vals.push(p.textContent));
  let sortArr = vals.slice(0);
  sortArr.sort().forEach(val => {
    oDiv.appendChild(ps[vals.indexOf(val)])
  })
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sortByOrdnr()"> Button </button>
<div id="container">
  <p class="ordernummer"> A </p>
  <p class="ordernummer"> E </p>
  <p class="ordernummer"> B </p>
  <p class="ordernummer"> C </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.innerHTML` to get the inside content. and sort and add it to the class elements.

```js
function sortByOrdnr() {

        var allaOrdnr = document.getElementsByClassName("ordernummer");

        var antal = allaOrdnr.length;

        var listWithAllaOrdnr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < antal; i++) {
          listWithAllaOrdnr.push(allaOrdnr[i].innerHTML);
        }

        listWithAllaOrdnr.sort() // [A, B, C, E]

        for (var i = 0; i < antal; i++) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("ordernummer")[i].innerHTML = listWithAllaOrdnr[i];

        }


      }
```

```html
<button onclick="sortByOrdnr()"> Button </button>

    <p class="ordernummer"> A </p>
    <p class="ordernummer"> E </p>
    <p class="ordernummer"> B </p>
    <p class="ordernummer"> C </p>
```

Comment: @LMinor accept the answer, if it solved your issue. for future users to find it easy.

Answer (score 0):

Here a snippet that may help you, you should use `.innerHTML` to set the new content:

```js
    function sortByOrdnr() {
        var allaOrdnr = document.getElementsByClassName("ordernummer");
        var antal = allaOrdnr.length;
        var listWithAllaOrdnr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < antal; i++) {
          listWithAllaOrdnr.push(allaOrdnr[i].innerText);
        }
        listWithAllaOrdnr.sort() // [A, B, C, E]
        for (var i = 0; i < antal; i++) {
          allaOrdnr[i].innerHTML = listWithAllaOrdnr[i];
        }
      }
```

```html
<button onclick="sortByOrdnr()"> Button </button>

    <p class="ordernummer"> A </p>
    <p class="ordernummer"> E </p>
    <p class="ordernummer"> B </p>
    <p class="ordernummer"> C </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  let container   = document.querySelector('div.container');
  let paragraphs  = container.querySelectorAll('p.ordernummer');
  
  let dataContainer = [];

  paragraphs.forEach(function(p){
    dataContainer.push(p.innerText);
  }); 

  let sorted = dataContainer.sort(function(next, current){
    if (current.toLowerCase() > next.toLowerCase()) return -1;
    if (current.toLowerCase() < next.toLowerCase()) return 1;
    return 0;
  });

  paragraphs.forEach(function(p, i){
    p.innerText = sorted[i];
  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <p class="ordernummer"> B </p>
  <p class="ordernummer"> A </p>
  <p class="ordernummer"> E </p>
  <p class="ordernummer"> C </p>
  <p class="ordernummer"> D </p>
 </div>
 <button>Sort em</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are inserting AND changing innerHTML - just do ONE of them. Like mine or one of the other answers

Comment: @mplungjan Right